# UIACollection view total cell count issue

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, ios-ui-automation, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on UIAutomation for an app and facing some issue while collecting the cells for a collection view on the app.

When I do `collectionView.cells()` in javascript for UIAutomation, I get back only the cells which are visible, but I do have more cells inside the collection view when I scroll down through the app.

Did anybody run through the same issue? Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to the answer I gave here ([UIACollectionView cells vs visibleCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789905/uiacollectionview-cells-vs-visiblecells/13793922#13793922)). Collection views only list visible cells for some reason. The documentation is incorrect.